# Browser interacting with python script

Tags: python, user-interaction

Iam working on small app where user writes program and execute them from browser. First thought of going with PHP but i didn't find a way to INTERACT with running program. Then I found Python and as of now Iam using subprocess.Popen. Now everything is running fine in Python Interpreter. Now how to send the output to browser and take inputs from it and send it to Interpreter ?

Was thinking about Pipes but once I call communicate() pipe closes. So which is the best way.

Another method I thought of is create GUI for existing program using HTML. Is it possible?

Comment: making an http server and using HTML templates is possible and quite simple with Python, you can just code your own web-server and do everything in python keeping everything web-ish without using cumbersome solutions like IPC or more complicated stuff.

Comment: any tutorials or example for that? So that means we'll use HTML, AJAX for this?

Comment: First, you must understand web applications concepts, wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application has a comprehensive coverage about web and web applications architecture, after reading it, you can google about web apps interaction methodologies like AJAX, Async, etc..., now you're ready to start building your app using modern web framework like Flask: flask.pocoo.org or django: djangoproject.com

Comment: yeah i read about django and thought maybe its overkill for my application. Any easy way for this?